# Do Jpa methods create their own transactions?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, transactions

I was wondering whether jpa methods execute within transactions or without them.
If i introduce @Transactioanl annotation, i understand that all the database queries within the scope of the annotation will execute within a single transaction.

Does that mean a @Transactional annotation overrides jpa methods' transaction settings, or is it that jpa methods, by themselves do not create a transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - Yes , JPA Methods save and saveAll do create their own transactions:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-save-saveall